Quotient of the unit interval
Assume $J_1, J_2, J_3, ...$ is a sequence of disjoint closed intervals in $[0, 1]$. Introduce an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $[0, 1]$: if $x\neq y$, then $x\sim y$ iff there is $k$ such that $x, y\in J_k$. Question: is there a good way to describe the quotient space $[0, 1]/\sim$ ? For example, are all such quotient space homeomorphic to a closed interval?
In some special cases, e.g. the intervals are $[\frac 13, \frac 23]$, $[\frac 19, \frac 29]$, $[\frac 79, \frac 89]$, ... (like the closure of intervals you remove in order to make the Cantor set), I think I can prove $[0, 1]/\sim$ is homeomorphic to $[0, 1]$. But in general I don't know how to proceed...

Do you want your intervals to be connected? Otherwise there is an easy example where the quotient space is homeomorphic to $S^1$.
